# Fixed ratio page auto scale

Tags: javascript, css

I have this table. I need to style it to always be in 16 by 9 ratio withn the top row taking up a fixed amount and the bottom row  taking up the rest of the page. A single font size across the whole table and the whole thing centered with page when the screen isn't 16 by 9

```
<body class="clock">
        <table class="clocktable">
            <tr>
                <td id="clock" class="time">
                00:00:00</td>
                <td id="timer" class="timing">
                00:00:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" id="eventnotes" class="notesevent">
                Here</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
```

The solution need to work on desktop browsers as well as mobile.
I know i could do it with java script and resize every element based on the page width, However I feel that there should be a better way.

Comment: post the code you tried, explain what exactly is not working with it.

Comment: don't use `async: false` there are a multitude of ways to manage asynchronous requests without needing to block the UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have decided to use Javascript and jQuery. The table is styled to 100% width and height of page. The bottom row fills the page because the top row has its height specified.

```
function resize() 
{
    var textheight = (($(window).width()) / 10);
    clocktable.style.fontSize = (textheight) + 'px';
    clock.style.height = (textheight*1.2) + 'px';
}

$(document).ready(function() {resize()});
$(window).resize(function() {resize()});
```

Here is my script.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are having problems with accessing keys of the javascript objects. You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) for this. You can use [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate through an array. See my code below

```js
var json = {
  "20:34:05": {
    "192.168.1.208": "foo"
  },
  "20:34:12": {
    "192.168.1.208": "bar"
  },
  "20:34:21": {
    "192.168.1.210": "bar foo"
  }
}


$.each(Object.keys(json), function(i, val) {
  var time = val;
  var ip = Object.keys(json[val])[0];
  var message = json[val][ip];

  console.log(time + " " + ip + " " + message);
})
```

Comment: can loop an object with `$.each` without needing to use `Object.keys()`. Easier to read

Comment: I like that it assigns time to val in this case. It made iteration more logical for me.